# Java.net Which goes fastest when you parse html from online?

Tags: java, io

Using java.net, java.io, what is the fastest way to parse html from online, and load it to a file or the console? Is buffered writer/buffered reader faster than inputstreamreader/outputstreamwriter? Are writers and readers faster than outputstreams and inputstreams?
I am experiencing serious lag with the following output writer/stream:

```
URLConnection ii;
BufferedReader iik = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ii.getInputStream()));

String op;

while(iik.readLine()!=null) {
    op=iik.readLine();
    System.out.println(op);
}
```

But curiously i am experiencing close to no lagtime with the following code:

```
URLConnection ii=i.openConnection();
Reader xh=new InputStreamReader(ii.getInputStream());

int r;
Writer xy=new PrintWriter(System.out);

while((r=xh.read())!=-1) {
    xy.write(r);
}  

xh.close();
xy.close();
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, how do you initialize `ii` in the first scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readers/Writers shouldn't be inherently faster than Input/OutputStreams.

That said, going through `readLine()` and `println()` probably isn't the optimal way of transferring bytes. In your case, if the file you're loading doesn't contain many newline characters, BufferedReader will have to buffer a lot of data before readLine() will return.

The canonical non-terrible way of transferring data between streams is doing it in chunks by using a buffer:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1<<12];
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
int read = -1;

while ((read = in.read(buf) != -1) {
    System.out.write(buf, 0, read);
}
```

It might be faster yet to use NIO, the code for it is a little less straightforward and I just use the one found in [this blog post](http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/fast-stream-copy-using-javanio-channels/).

If you're writing to/from a file, the best method is to use a zero-copy approach, which Java makes available with [`FileChannel.transferFrom()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29) and `transferTo()`. Sample code is available in [a DeveloperWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/j-zerocopy/).

Comment: Thanks for this byte array example. The faster code snippets on the blog links as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your first snippet is wrong: it reads the next line, tests if it's null, ignores it, then reads the next line without testing if it's null, and prints it.

The second code prints the integer value of every char read from the reader.

Both snippets use the same underlying streams and readers, and, if coded correctly, the first one should probably be a bit faster thanks to buffering. But of course, you'll have something printed on the screen only when the line is ended. If the server sends a single line of text of 10 MBs, you'll have to read the whole 10 MBs before something is printed to the screen.

Make sure to close the readers in finally blocks.

Comment: that would probably explain why the first example (coded with two nextline calls) takes forever. Thanks very much.